# If $X$ is an affine algebraic set, how is $A(X)$ finitely generated as a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, definition

**If $X$ is an affine algebraic set, how is $A(X)$ finitely generated as a ring?**

---

---

---

This comes from a remark in Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra* after Corollary 9.30"

> > > [image]

> > > [image]

Comment: Isn't $A(X)$ a quotient of $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ for some $n$?

Comment: Would that classify as a finitely generated ring? Wouldn't that classify as a finitely generated $k$-algebra?

Comment: I suspect that is a typo, and as you say, this should say that $A(X)$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra. Since all the maps involved are $k$-algebra homomorphisms, this is all that should be needed (well, as far as I can tell without actually looking at any proofs).

Comment: @AlJebr That's a good point, I guess it's not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra (depending on what $k$ is, e.g., $k = \mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Also, if use the hypothesis that $A(X)$ is integral over $A(Y)$, why does $A(X)$ being finitely generated ring make no difference in the claim?